# RazorPages anchor tag helper with multiple parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Here's the RazorPages page I'm trying to make a link to:

```
@page "{ReportId:int}/{SicCode:alpha?}"
```

This works

```
<a asp-page="/ReportSics" asp-route-ReportId="3">rs1</a>
```

it produces

```
<a href="/Reports/ReportSics/3">rs1</a>
```

But this produces a blank `href`.

```
<a asp-page="/ReportSics" asp-route-ReportId="3" asp-route-SicCode="10">rss2</a>
```

That is: the tag helper works with one parameter but not with two.
Why? 
Is it possible to make it work?

(I have another page with the same `@page` but with the second parameter not optional and it appears to be impossible to create a link to it.)

Furthermore, requesting `Page/2/M` works, but `Page/2/12` returns 404. Why? (The second parameter is a string that can sometimes be a number, but it always treated as a string.)

Answer (score 1):

From the learn.microsoft.com webpage [asp-all-route-data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0#asp-all-route-data) offers the following:

> **asp-all-route-data**
>
> The asp-all-route-data attribute supports the creation of a dictionary of key-value pairs. The key is the parameter name, and the value is the parameter value.
>
> In the following example, a dictionary is initialized and passed to a Razor view. Alternatively, the data could be passed in with your model.

```
@{
var parms = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "speakerId", "11" },
                { "currentYear", "true" }
            };
}

<a asp-route="speakerevalscurrent"
   asp-all-route-data="parms">Speaker Evaluations</a>
```

> The preceding code generates the following HTML:

```
<a href="/Speaker/EvaluationsCurrent?speakerId=11&currentYear=true">Speaker Evaluations</a>
```

**Extension**:  From here the parameters can be accessed either explicitly in the parameter list of the method:

```
public IActionResult EvaluationCurrent(int speakerId, string currentYear)
```

or as a collection (See response:  [queryString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73962443/3926065):

```
public IActionResult EvaluationCurrent() 
{
     var queryString = this.Request.Query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This works

Yes it works because it produces a route that is similar to this `baseUrl/reportsics/?reportId=5`
And the other produces a URL that is similar to this `baseUrl/reportsics/?reportId=5&sicCode=678` and then it doesn't match your route definition. I think you should try this.
**Experimental**

```
asp-page="/reportSics/@myId/@sicCode
```

Though this would not be the right way to do what you're thinking. If you really want to change your URL structure, why not do url-rewrite?
**Edit**. 
Form your recent comments, seems you want to pass many parameters in your action method and not targeting URL structure. Then I recommend you just

```
public IActionResult(string ReportId, string sicCode)
{
  //......
}

//And the your URL target
<a asp-page="ReportSics" asp-route-ReportId="55" asp-route-sicCode="566" ></a>
```

And then it will match the route. I think you should remove that helper you placed after your `@page` definition and try it out if this is what you have already done and the problem persists.

Comment: So how should I be doing this?

Is my `@page` wrong?
Or do I need to add things to `Startup.cs`?
Or am I using `asp-page` and `asp-route` wrong?

Comment: I'd really like to make a `href` from a page name stored in a `string` and a `Dictionary<string, string>` of parameter values. I thought that `asp-page` and `asp-route-all-data` would do exactly this, but apparently not?

Comment: So it looks like if I get rid of the parameters from `@page` then it goes back to doing normal GET parameters and I can build URLs using `string.Join("&",...)`.

So what is the point of the URL helper if it just plain doesn't work if you have more than one parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if a parameter has the constraint `:alpha` then it only works if the value being passed can not be parsed as an `int` or `float`.