# How do you access all querystring parameters as a dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have some dynamic querystring parameters that I would like to interact with as an `IDictionary<string,string>` or similar?  How do I do this?

For example.  How can I interpret multiple (varying in quantity) variables for a query similar to:

```
/{area}/{controller}/{action}?alert=primary&msg=Success
```

[Parallel question for asp.net-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419823/how-to-access-all-querystring-parameters-as-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Query` method on the `AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest` to get the parsed query string as a collection of key-value pairs.

```
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var queryString = this.Request.Query;
}
```

Additionally, [How to read values from the QueryString](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41577376/3926065) provides a nice summary of the methods to access and use the `IQueryCollection` that is created in this approach.

Specifically:  [ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41577487/3926065) and [Inclusion in Method Parameter List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41577446/3926065).